# Given two lists of sums of variables times a constant, find the list of sums of the variables with maximum constants

Tags: linear-algebra, functions

We are given two lists:

$$
c_{1,1} * x_1 + c_{1,2} * x_2 + c_{1,3} * x_3 + ....
$$

and

$$
c_{2,1} * x_1 + c_{2,2} * x_2 + c_{2,3} * x_3 + ....
$$

Where we know all values of c (greater than or equal to 0, but for the sake of simplicity you can assume they are 0 or 1), but we do not know the x values, nor do we have partial sums. Is there a way to find (or approximate) the list:
$$
max(c_{2,1},c_{1,1}) * x_1 + max(c_{2,2},c_{1,2}) * x_2 + max(c_{2,3},c_{1,3}) * x_3 + ....
$$

If more convenient, you can also use vector notation:
$$
c_1^Tx 
$$

and

$$
c_2^Tx 
$$

Find

$$
elmax(c_1, c_2)^Tx 
$$

Where elmax is the element-wise max operation and c (whose values are known) and x (whose values are unknown) are N dimensional vectors.

This way you would have

$$
c_{max}^Tx = (c1^Tx + c2^Tx + |c1^T - c2^T|x)/2
$$

Where the |*| takes the element wise absolute of a vector/matrix. Thus all you would need to do is approximate:
$$
|c1^T - c2^T|x
$$

Which is the main thing I am struggling with. x does not commute into the operation, as not all its elements are positive. While you may not know x, you do know stastical properties about its elements, such as their mean, standard deviation, etc. as well as per inner product statistical information (so for all x values where c1 is greater than 0 and likewise for c2.

With the vector notation and c elements being 0 or 1, you have |c1 - c2| being an element-wise XOR operation and elmax(c1,c2) an element-wise OR operator, if that helps you.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this can help, but here I write an objection.
Obiously, $c_{max}^Tx $ can be bounded by
$$ \frac{c_1x + c_2x}{2} \leq c_{max}x \leq c_1x + c_2x $$
About a better bound, it is impossible unless more information is given. Consider the simple example with 3 dimensions:
$$c_1 = (1,0,1) \quad c_2 = (1,1,0) \quad c_1^Tx = 1 \quad c_2^T x= 1 $$

if $x = (1,0,0)$ then $c_{max}x = 1 $ which is the lower bound.

if $x = (0,1,1)$ then $c_{max}x = 2 $ which is the upper bound.

I hope this message could help.